# Swift UIBarButtonItem Missing Image on Pressed

Tags: swift, swift4

UI Navigation Icon is done programmatically using SwiftIcons framework ...

```
let searchBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchBtnAction))
        searchBarButton.setIcon(icon: .openIconic(.magnifyingGlass), iconSize: 20, color: .white)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchBarButton]
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
```

[image: Display from above code...]
[image: When icon is pressed..]

how can i resolve this.. so the question mark (missing) icon wont appear

Comment: So, what happened between the first and the second screen shot?

Comment: What does setIcon do?  Show the code for that?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth `setIcon` is from the SwiftIcons  framework; I think it works with unicode characters, so the problem might have been caused by missing fonts. But then I still don't know why it's shown in the top screenshot, but missing in the bottom screenshot. Still waiting for a reply by @swipx

Comment: @AndreasOetjen thanks for that I completely missed that in the question.  From the question I assumed image one is unpressed and image two is when the button is pressed.

Comment: I checked out the SwiftIcons framework and couldn't see a setIcon method for UIBarButtonItem only an icon method.  Is there something I am missing or is setIcon part of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved in the SwiftIcons Library version 2.0.1 on January 13rd (or so).

To solve, you'll have to update the `SwiftIcons.swift` source file, or your podfile: `pod 'SwiftIcons', '~> 2.0.1'` or whatever you use.

The problem was in the extension method `UIBarButtonItem.setIcon` which should look like this in the correct version:

```
public func setIcon(icon: FontType, iconSize: CGFloat, color: UIColor = .black) {

    FontLoader.loadFontIfNeeded(fontType: icon)
    let font = UIFont(name: icon.fontName(), size: iconSize)
    assert(font != nil, icon.errorAnnounce())
    setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .normal)
    setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .highlighted)
    setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .disabled)
    setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .focused)
    title = icon.text
    tintColor = color
}
```

The main change was to set the text attributes for all the different control states (*normal*, *highlighted* and so on).

Using this most recent version, you should be fine.

Comment: Updating the Pod and adding the lines solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: thank you Andreas! This solve the issue! I added the following lines to `SwiftIcons.swift`


     `setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .highlighted)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .disabled)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!], for: .focused)`